# A random frame around icon

Tags: windows-7, icons

I would like to know why for some icons on my desktop (I am using Windows 7) I see a frame around the link icon for some app (even though the app to which the link points have icon without surrounding frame), and for some I do not. You can see on the picture what I mean:
[image]

Also I would like to know how I can remove this frame if this is possible.
I would greatly appreciate any hint regarding the matter.

Comment: What happens if you press `←` or `→` while the frame is there? Does it appear only on that shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual, and it's because the Icon with the frame around it doesn't have a 256x256 RGB layer that's used in Vista+ for icons larger than "Medium".

Here's an example...

Two icons, one with frame (right), one without (left):

[image]

Layers in icon *with* frame (Orange one):

[image]

Layers in icon *without* frame (Red one):

[image]